# iPhone development

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am new to iPhone development. I want to make a simple iPhone application which when launched computes the distance travelled by the user,calories burnt,postion of the user,movement.Can anybody provide me the details or approach to follow to develop this application.

Comment: General steps: get a Mac. Download Xcode, install it and start it. Create a new iPhone application using the offered choices. ??? Profit!

Comment: Break your problem down into smaller questions.  We're not here to write your application for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, follow the steps outlined in the following links:

- [iPhone Programming Tutorial](http://icodeblog.com/)
- [iPhone Development Guide: Quick Start](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/xcode/conceptual/iphone_development/100-iPhone_Development_Quick_Start/iphone_development_quick_start.html)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunetely, it's not *that* simple.

You will have to learn xCode/Objective C/C#.

I suggest you start by getting a book, i recommend:

> Beginning iPhone Development - Mark
>   LaMarche
> iPhone for Programmers: An
>   app driven approach
> The iPhone
>   developers cookbook

You **should** be able to find these as eBooks as well (if that's what you like).

---

Unless you want a *step by step* tutorial for a fitness program... Then you'll be out of luck.

Comment: Once you learn to write apps you'll need to integrate 3D acceleration and orientation data from the accelerometer and magnetometers, [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733249/detecting-acceleration-in-a-car-iphone-accelerometer) might help in that.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is inside the Core Location framework (and some math).
If you don't know how to use the Core Location framework, just look at the Apple developer page, there are tons of sample code (and they should also have some sample video from the last techtalk)

Answer (score 0):

It would have been better if you could ask a direct question rather than sharing an app idea. Which major problem areas you are facing while developing the app,
For initial iPhone  app development, I will suggest to go through following link:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/
For your application, you will need Location services, which should run in background too (while the application is in background) you can also consider content on Apple website:
https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201357
More over you will be able to calculate the distance covered, position and movement, through location services and based on this information and custom information provided by user, you will  be able to calculate the calories burnt by applying simple math (totally depends on the logic you want to apply).