# How to find acceleration of running Shipping Boat from iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, acceleration

I am trying to calculate the acceleration of running Shipping boats from IPhone but i did't found any relevant information regarding this. If any one have done this type of requirement earlier please suggest me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Once check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733249/detecting-acceleration-in-a-car-iphone-accelerometer

Comment: checkout this app https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yQZOUIwXAJc    they got speed and time..then you can calculate acceleration.

Comment: we can find the speed and time by using this below code snippet-          -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    CLLocation *loc = locations.lastObject;
    double speed = loc.speed;
    NSLog(@"%f", speed);
}and how can we find the acceleration by using these two.

Comment: Acceleration is change in velocity (speed) over time. Just take the difference in speed now compared to a few seconds (minutes?) ago and you have the relative acceleration.